# Is this asterisk character in my switch the reason I'm having a paradox in the output?

Tags: php, operators, switch-statement, var-dump

In a PHP script I have this code:

```
 $route = new Route($url);
 var_dump($route->getRouteIDs());
 
 echo "<br/>";
 $isValid = $route->isValid($url);
 var_dump($isValid);
 
 echo "<br/>";
 switch($isValid) {
     case '*':
         echo "wildcard route";
         break;
     case true:
         echo "real route";
         break;
     case false:
         echo "false route";
         break;
 }
```

This is the output:

> array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "21" }
>
> bool(true)
>
> wildcard route

In the output, lines 1 & 2 are as expected. But to me, it looks like the results of lines 2 and lines 3 are contradicting each other.

Why is the switch being activated for the asterisk (*) character when the var_dump is saying the variable $isValid contains only a boolean 'true' value?

Comment: What's the point of `echo var_dump(...)`? `var_dump` prints output, it doesn't return anything useful.

Comment: @Barmar purely debugging purposes for the sake of this question.

Comment: I mean why did you write `echo var_dump(...)` instead of just `var_dump(...)`?

Comment: I removed the echo's. Doesn't really matter. Issue still remains and is separate.

Answer (score 3):

`switch` performs loose comparisons. In this case, `true` compares equal to any truthy value. You can see it with this simple test:

```
if ('*' == true) {
    echo "Wildcard route";
}
```

If you want strict comparisons, you'll have to write out the `if/then/elseif` statements, using `===` as the comparison operator.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know `switch` performed loose comparisons and using `===` returned expected results.